# Closures instance inside closure

Tags: php, closures, autoload

I'm trying to figure out if my autoload function is the last loader, so that i can throw an exception.
Of course i could make a loader class and check the class, but where is than fun in that.

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){  
    if (stripos($class, __NAMESPACE__) !== 0) {
        $autoloaders = spl_autoload_functions();
        if(\Closure == $autoloaders[count($autoloaders)-1]){
            throw new Exception('Sorry mac, no more autoloading for u!');
        }
        return; // let next autoloader give it a try
    }
    // some logic for loading
});
```

Comment: And your question is? Are you getting an error? Is there something you don't know how to do?